# Save File Dialog says file is being used by another process Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, savefiledialog

I'm making a program that opens, edits, and saves text files. So far, the opening and editing parts are working (but there's a bug with the editing part, I'll get to that later, worst case is I'll have to change the form some but I'm sure I can fix it). My main problem is the save part. Honestly, I don't know what I'm doing when it comes to Open/Save File Dialog, so I really have no idea where to begin fixing it.

I go to save a file, and I save it as a .txt file with any name (new file or overwrite it doesn't matter) and then it gives me an exception that says "The file is being used by another process" even if it's a brand new file. Here's the source:

```
        Dim myStream As Stream
        Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
        saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".txt"
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "New File.txt"

        If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString, txtOutput.Text, True)
            End If
        End If
```

Comment: It is not lying.  Don't use OpenFile().  If you for some mysterious reason only want to overwrite existing files then use OpenFileDialog instead.

Comment: At a glance, you create a stream for the file (when you call `OpenFile`.  You then try to write to the file you just opened, before you close the stream, hence the lock (file being used by another process)..  You don't need to open the file - `WriteAllText` will create the file, overwrite or append, IIRC.